# How to back-up MySQL in a snap

Tags: mysql, snap

I've installed NextCloud in a snap under Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.  The MySQL installation in the snap uses a socket file locate in the snap's (containerized) /tmp rather than a network socket.  I don't want to reconfigure the snap's MySQL configuration to add a network listener, as I expect that such changes might get lost with upgrades or re-installations.

I want to back up NextCloud's MySQL environment using mysqldump, but without a network listener I need to know the location of the socket file as it appears to the host (non-snap) environment.  At the moment, I've found the socket appears to the host system as "/tmp/snap.0_nextcloud_eKluT5/tmp/sockets/mysql.sock", but I don't think that path will stay consistent.  Is there a way to dynamically query the mappings between the snap environment and the host environment (e.g. the snap's /tmp maps to the hosts /tmp/snap.0_nextcloud_eKluT5/tmp)?